# the correct order of filters in web.xml for a grails application

Tags: grails, filter, web.xml

the web.xml of my groovy application has some filters, filtermappings, servlet mappings, listeners defined in the following exact order:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.4">
    <display-name>/gra-production-0.1</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
                     /WEB-INF/security-app-context.xml
                </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>myapp-production-0.1</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>urlMapping</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethod</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>grailsWebRequest</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
            <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
                <param-value>characterEncodingFilter</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
            <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
            <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethod</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>grailsWebRequest</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>urlMapping</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>grails</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>gsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>grails-errorhandler</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>gsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.gsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>grails-errorhandler</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/grails-errorhandler</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>grails</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.dispatch</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
      </listener>

</web-app>
```

Right now the server starts up fine but when I hit my application URL I get a grails runtime exception as follows:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes cannot be cast to org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest

    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest(WebUtils.java:497)
```

I think its an issue with the order of loading of filters and filter mappings..not sure what the correct order should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading to v1.2.5 of the plugin. It correctly orders filter-mapping elements (there was an issue with the resources plugin which also has strict element ordering rules).

One thing that looks weird is there are two `</filter-mapping>` end tags after the 'springSecurityFilterChain' filter-mapping. Is this file edited?

Comment: Thanks Burt.. yes, I had 2 definitions for springsecurityfilterchain, had one commented but removed it incompletely for posting here..., I will be upgrading the plugin and trying again, but I just had one related question using spring security with grails. I know we can configure spring security either using the grails plugins or by xml configuration. I am supposing one is grails specific and other is old-wired method, can we do both in the same application?

Comment: No, I use a different approach than traditional Spring Security, in particular with bean names. It'd be a lot of work to figure out how to get them to work together, and traditional Spring Security using XML isn't all that much work, so it's best to just pick one.