# Grails Servlet Filter Madness: ...ServletRequestAttributes cannot be cast to..GrailsWebRequest

Tags: servlets, grails, amf

I have a Grails backend with a Flex Single Page Application acting as the UI.  For some reason, when I make an AMF request, my app conks out. with the following error (parts truncated for readability)

```
2014-04-20 21:07:55,572 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  -      
ClassCastException occurred when processing request: [POST]   
/OrlandoGrails/messagebroker/amf
org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes cannot be cast to 
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.ClassCastException:   
org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes cannot be cast to 
 org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest...
2014-04-20 21:07:55,573 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - 

Unable to render errors view: 
org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes cannot be cast to 
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest...
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes cannot be cast to 
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest
Servlet.service() for servlet [Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet] in context with path 
[/OrlandoGrails] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: 

java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes cannot be cast to 
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest] with root cause...
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes cannot be cast to 
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest at 
 grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53
```

I've read some of the other solutions on the web, and they say that I have to order my web.xml with my springSecurityFilter first and it's mapping last.  I have done that, and below is my web.xml template (before Grails gets ahold of it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
     metadata-complete="true"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<display-name>/@grails.project.key@</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>@grails.project.key@</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>characterEncodingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>grails</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>dispatchOptionsRequest</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>gsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>gsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.gsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<listener>
    <listener-class>flex.messaging.HttpFlexSession</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/messagebroker/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The url that is being accessed is  /blah/messagebroker/amf, so I would have thought that only the blazeds messagebroker handler would get ahold of the request, but clearly I am wrong.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems a bit odd that flex.messaging.MessageBrokerServlet is missing from your configuration. I'm not a Flex expert at all but I seem to recall you need a listener and the Servlet both within your Tomcat application. Similar to this: http://svn.codehaus.org/gfs/trunk/grails-flex-scaffold/trunk/FlexScaffoldGrailsPlugin.groovy or in XML version: http://www.pavlasek.sk/devel/?p=39

Comment: Have you tried the advice in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146498/the-correct-order-of-filters-in-web-xml-for-a-grails-application ?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the document ordering in the web.xml, `charEncodingFilter` will always be executed before the `sitemesh` filter.

I'm speculating, but it seems that the `ServletRequestAttribute` instance created by `charEncodingFilter` is being cast to the wrong type when the `sitemesh` filter is executed.

Have you tried swapping the positions of the `filter-mapping`s? Something like:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```